# Laravel - Creating bootstrap dropdown with headers

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, laravel

I am trying to add a "category" header to the dropdown menu as

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu3">
  ...
  <li class="dropdown-header">Dropdown header</li>
  ...
</ul>
```

The database record is like,

```
..., Category 1, Item 1
..., Category 1, Item 2
..., Category 2, Item 1
```

The blade file is as following,

```
@foreach ($records as $record)
  <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" data-target="#">{{$record->Item}}</a></li>
@endforeach
```

How can I add `$record->Category` into this dropdown so it can be shown as nested as the following,

```
Category 1
  Item 1
  Item 2
Category 2
  Item 1
  ...
```

Answer (score 3):

Thanks @mina-youssef , I got it work with something like below:

```
@foreach ($records->unique('Category') as $record_parrent)
  <li class="dropdown-header">{{$record_parrent->Category}}</li>
  @foreach ($records->where('Category',$record_parrent->Category) as $record_child)
    <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" data-target="#">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;{{$record_child->Item}}</a></li>
  @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass it through an iterator first to build multi-dimensional array. Something like that:

```
foreach ($items as $item)
{
  $array[$item->category][] = $item->item;
}
```

Then in your blade go through two `@foreach` statements.

Comment: Using this suggestion or another way?

Comment: I used two @foreach statements.